# How to detect the request come from Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I wonder whether or not exists some flag or tag that the website can use it to detect the request came from Puppeteer?

When I ran my code based on Puppeteer to visit the target website, I found that the website seems to know the request was made by Puppeteer.

How can it do?

Comment: I think it may be because of Chrome setup some header in the request when it runs under "automated test software" mode.
But I can't find that “header” in Dev-tools or fiddler~

And in order to test, I run the request by the same chromium manually, Everything is OK, The website does what I expected.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running the puppeteer and would like to pass some information to the website to catch your crawling, the best way to do so would be to set a custom user agent:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--user-agent=hhh'],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

See [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1697) more info

Viceversa, if you own a website and would like to know if the visits are real or from a bot (puppeteer, a scraper, or anything else) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364643/headless-browser-detection) for some of them.
Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998010/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-web-client-is-a-puppeteer-instance)

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to cross the limitation. It's an easy way:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],});
```

This will let the browser to not setup `navigator.webdriver` variable.